# Windows Mobile (MFC). CListView with buttons instead of usual strings?

Tags: list, listview, button, mfc, windows-mobile

i have no idea how to realize this feature.

My temporary solution is to place a fixed number of visible CBitmapButton and a scrollbar. Then I handle the scrollbar position changing and choose the appropriate appearance of the placed buttons.

Answer (score 0):

With normal (not Mobile) MFC, the answer would be to put the CListView into Icon mode (LVS_ICON), and use an CImageList with the bitmaps. This offers 32x32 icons, and there is also a LVS_SMALLICON mode for 16x16 icons.  These options may also be available for Mobile.

Comment: sorry, but it is not appropriate for be because I need a scrollable list of buttons with pictures which are approximatelly 100x200